# Using git with Wordpress and multiple people: access all files locally but only edit a subset?

Tags: wordpress, git

git `n00b` here.  My boss and I are developing a `wordpress` workflow with git.  We'd like to have a copy of all the files on our local machines, but 95% of time we only want to edit a certain theme folder.  But our efforts so far haven't yielded a working solution yet.  Here's what I've tried:

I originally set my repository to include all `wordpress` files, so I could always get latest core files from server.  Then I discovered files on server were getting overwritten by local copies even if I didn't edit them (eg i do a `wordpress` update on server and next time I push from local, the old files overwrite the newer ones on server)

So I used git ignore to drill all the way down to my theme folder.  Git was still tracking them, so I used rm to stop tracking.  But then git deleted all the other files.

How do people here use git with multiple people to update Wordpress?  Any perspectives much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should keep all the files in your git repository, but you should avoid doing any modifications directlry on the server.

Your wordpress update should be done on any of your local checkout of the repository and then pushed on the server via git.

Another possibility will be to commit / push the update changes once they have been done on the server, but I would prefer working locally and then deploying the update.

Comment: Thanks!  How would I commit changes on server?  Everything I read talks about committing locally

Comment: Also another way server changes could happen - people make modifications to database via website.  99% of those would happen via server as people who don't have git would go in and change text, images, create pages, etc.  although it may be case actual database is stored somewhere outside of Wordpress folder, I want to look into more.  I just see a MySQL file in there.